# How to pass parameters to svcutil

Tags: web-services, visual-studio-2010, wcf, c#-4.0, svcutil.exe

I am trying to generate the proxy file from wcf service using svcutil.exe, but I didn't understand how to pass the parameters to svcutil to collection type as system.Collections.Generic.List

I tried the below command in visual studio command prompt.

```
svcutil http://localhost:19021/InterviewManagementService/InterviewManagementService.svc /l:C# /out:Reference.cs /config /s /ct:System.Collections.Generic.List`1 /t:code /n:*,newnamespace
```

Please correct me with the above command.

Comment: what framework do you use? and what troubles do you have? do you want to simply generate Reference.cs?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to specify the assembly for the referenced collection types (more info [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347850(v=vs.110).aspx)).

> When using the Svcutil.exe tool, this reference can be accomplished by using the /collectionType command-line switch (short form: /ct). Keep in mind that you must also specify the assembly for the referenced collection types using the /reference switch (short form: /r). If the type is generic, it must be followed by a back quote and the number of generic parameters. The back quote (`) is not to be confused with the single quote (‘) character. You can specify multiple referenced collection types by using the /collectionType switch more than once.

So you need to add `/r:C:\full_path_to_system_dll\System.dll` to your command right before `/ct:System.Collections.Generic.List`